# Is there a way to completely flush cached AD credentials on a user workstation?

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, authentication, login

An AD user updated their AD password, but a couple applications on their workstation appear to still be using their old AD credentials.  Is there an easy way to flush out cached AD credentials on Windows (short of logging out or rebooting)?

A few google searches hinted at "gpupdate /force" but I wasn't sure if that would encompass stuff like NTLM credentials and AD passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be looking for the "Credential Manager" which can really only be run locally:

You can start it from the command line:

```
control userpasswords2
```

Then go to the second tab (Advanced) then select "Manage Passwords", this will let you modify saved network passwords for the current user on that computer.

Comment: If the user is not an administrator they will not be able to access this; and unable to clear their stored passwords.